# How to install ssl certificate to Apache2 by editing httpd.conf on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: ssl, apache2

I'm trying to install ssl certificate to Apache2 by editing httpd.conf on Amazon Linux 2, and I already put those three files in correct location. If I don't add the code below, Apache2 can start properly without ssl certificate. However, after I add code below and try to restart Apache2, I got an error message :

Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Here is my code:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.****.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I stuck here for several hours. Does anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't post text as image. And check [help/on-topic] and the [tag:apache] tag description as this is not programming related but a configuration question

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I just found using wrong tag.  @OlafKock